# GNU make `foreach`: get rid of comma in the last list member?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am using a `foreach` to generate a list in a GNU makefile:

```
DEFINES += DEF1
DEFINES += DEF2
...
MY_DEFINES := $(foreach define,$(DEFINES),\"$(define)\",\n)
```

When I print the defines into a file

```
echo -e "$(MY_DEFINES)";
```

I get the following:

```
DEF1,
DEF2,
```

How do I get rid of a comma in the last list member?
My output needs to be:

```
DEF1,
DEF2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way it to use `head` to cut off the last 2 bytes, e.g.:

```
echo -e "$(MY_DEFINES)" | head --bytes=-2
```

Another way is to prefix each element with `,\n` apart from the first element:

```
MY_DEFINES := $(firstword ${DEFINES})$(foreach define,$(wordlist 2,$(words ${DEFINES}),${DEFINES}),\n,\"$(define)\")
```

Comment: I think this will leave the first word non-hyphenated ("") and the last one without \n, although both are easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

A step-by-step solution could be:

```
COMA    := ,
DEFINES += DEF1
DEFINES += DEF2
...
MY_DEFINES := $(patsubst %,%$(COMA),$(DEFINES))FOOBAR
MY_DEFINES := $(patsubst %$(COMA)FOOBAR,%,$(MY_DEFINES))
MY_DEFINES := $(patsubst %,%\n,$(MY_DEFINES))
```

Where `FOOBAR` is any string that you are 100% sure will never be part of one of your `DEFINES`.